# allow requests to gae endpoint only from a specific domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is it possibile to allow requests to a gae endpoint method only from a specific domain (e.g. www.myname.com) and refuse everything else?

I'm looking for something like an app authentication (I don't want a user login)

many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *from a specific domain*? Please give an example when the request should be accepted and when it should be rejected.

Comment: I mean that it should answer right to everything that comes from www.mydomain.com and refuse everything that comes from a different domain (eg www.somethingelse.com) ... on www.mydomain.com there should be a front-end written in javascript: I want that it is the only one who can call that endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out the following approach:

Inject the `HTTPServletRequest` parameter into your **APIMethod**.

> @ApiMethod(path = "resources/{id}")
>
> public Resource get(@Named("id") int id, **HttpServletRequest request**) {
>
> //Use the request parameter here...
>
> }

From the request parameter above, use the following:

> ```
> String host = request.getRemoteHost();
> ```

Keep in mind that the host value can be your client or proxy's host name.

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try, but how can I inject a servlet in the endpoint?
anyway as you say I don't think it is really a safe way to do so, isn't there any alternative? i found something about 2 legged oAuth but I cannot find how to use it with javascript and gae

Comment: When I mean inject, it means providing an extra parameter in your APIMethod signature. Check this out : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#injected_types

Comment: I have modified my answer to better explain injecting of the parameter.

Comment: If you get an IP address from getRemoteHost, you should convert it to hostname, and then check `hostName.endsWith(".mydomain.com")`.